# Possible to use Python program on node js Heroku Dyno?

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have a node js Dyno on Heroku and I've changed the script so it uses the npm python-shell module to communicate with a Python program I've written. I'd rather not translate the Python code to js as it is performance-sensitive and works best with certain python modules.

Is it possible to place the Python file in my deployment folder, push it to the Dyno and have it work somehow? I couldn't find much online for this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a node.js and Python environment on the same dyno by following [Heroku's advice on using multiple build packs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app):

You can type this into the Heroku shell:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
```

You then need to add the relevant Python start command into your Procfile so that both your Python and Node applications run side by side.